# How to get the NELL fact name from ID

Tags: web-scraping, groovy

I am currently working with NELL facts for which I need to extract their actual values. Since am new to NELL this question might sound trivial. But I have a predicate relationship as shown below;

**REL.txt**

```
Subject     Predicate   Object      Soft truth value
--------------------------------------------------------
'127760'    '130502'    '310'       0.42559126019477844
'273473'    '273477'    '65054'     0.4276425838470459
'192051'    '138949'    '181130'    0.4762486517429352
'120911'    '130624'    '310'       0.41060972213745117
'284689'    '220959'    '219678'    0.4190083146095276
```

This is the output of this [Knowledge-graph-identification example](https://github.com/linqs/psl-examples/tree/master/knowledge-graph-identification) from the PSL-examples repo. Mapping this to the NELL facts from which it takes the subject, object and predicates, how do I find the actual object that is represented by this ID and the percentage to which NELL is sure of it?

E.g. In the statement;
"***alaska*** is a city that ***lies on*** the river ***columbia*** (river) "

```
127760 → alaska
130502 → lies on
310    → colombia
```

**[NELL Relationships](http://rtw.ml.cmu.edu/rtw/kbbrowser/city:alaska)**

[image]

Any suggestions on a way to read the actual name of the entity or relationship represented by this ID, will be highly appreciated.I am working on a groovy script for the rest of the functionalities. But any programming language will be suffice as long as it accesses the actual name tied to the ID.